# Prevent parskip after special at beginning of vbox

Tags: paragraphs, plain-tex, parskip, specials

If I understand correctly, when entering unrestricted horizontal mode, TeX inserts a parskip if the containing vertical list is non-empty. That applies even when the only item on the list is not actually a paragraph, but e.g. a special:

```
\vbox{\special{}x}
```

Is there a way to prevent the parskip in this case?

More specifically, how would I write a macro `\foo` that involves `\special` and should work in both of these cases:

```
\vbox{\foo x}
\vbox{\foo\hbox{x}}
```

i.e. whether or not horizontal mode will be entered after the macro. The first case could be solved by adding `\leavevmode` to the macro, but for the second case, that is not an option.

But I can't detect during expansion of `\foo` if `\leavevmode` will be needed.

Comment: this is why `\color` sometimes affects spacing, it's bascally not soluable in classic tex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why `\color` sometimes affects spacing, it's basically not soluable in classic tex.

Using e-tex you can catch some cases

```
\tracingoutput1
\tracingonline1
\showboxdepth=6

\def\foo{%
\ifnum\currentgrouptype=4
\ifnum\lastnodetype=-1
\vbox\bgroup\aftergroup\foox
\else
\special{}%
\fi
\else
\special{}%
\fi}

\def\foox{\setbox0\lastbox\special{}\unvbox0\egroup}

\vbox{\foo x}

\bye
```

produces a box

```
..\vbox(4.30554+0.0)x469.75499
...\special{}
...\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 444.47719fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
....\tenrm x
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

where the special is immediately before the hbox with x.

This basically detects if it is at the start of a vbox and if so makes a vbox without the `\special` then re-boxes it after adding the `\special`  But using such code without breaking something is hard in real documents